# ImageList Transparency not working at runtime

Tags: c#-2.0, imagelist

I am using 32bit PNG files with transparency. I added them to an image list with properties:

```
ColorDepth: Depth32Bit
TransparentColor: Transparent
```

When I assign the image to my toolbar button, it previews in Visual Studio fine with the correct transparency. But when I run the application the transparency is all messed up with black covering the semi-transparent regions.

How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was a bug in the SWF 2.0 ImageList that would remove the alpha channel from 32 bit images in an image list *when saving the image list resources*. Are the images still shown correctly if you save and reload the form in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes the preview is still correct after saving and closing the form, or  restarting visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution apparently is to put

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Before the start of your application. This has fixed the transparency issue.

[Solution Reference](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/36/180549.aspx)

[MSDN on EnableVisualStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Ok, I have seen this problem occur before without that resolving it. I did wonder why your second screenshot looked so chunky!

Comment: I had this problem inside a Word add-in (Using AddinExpress). Adding Application.EnableVisualStyles() to my AddinModule's InitializeComponent method resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

If you add them directly to the toolbar without using an image list I think they will draw correctly.

Comment: Easy solution. I also prefer this way.

Comment: Well I would prefer to use an image list to make it easy to swap the images of the toolbar buttons (like the toggle inactive button).

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't change a toolbar button's text or icon at runtime. You can use a checkable button for that.

Comment: How do I add them directly to the toolbar?

Comment: I guess you are using SWF 1.1 style toolbar? I suggest using the 2.0 style ToolStrip instead. This not only adds some shine to your application, but also enables setting the images directly :)